# How to submit huge data forms using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I need to store data from a web page. There are many (80~100) input controls and I need to validate as submit the form as well. What would be the best practice, either get value one by one from every control or something better else?

Comment: Client side is faster but you can also use model validation

Answer (score 0):

That depends: when there are simple rules by which you validate your fields like checking phone numbers etc., you should do it client side before submitting. If there are some more complicated rules (or sensitive data neccessary for checking that you cannot expose to the user's browser), you should submit everything and validate server-side.

Comment: But i need to submit my form, would it be a good practice to save the form controls one by one or using serialization ?